# how to retrieve realtime textbox value and name via this keyword?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

i want to get textbox value for my javascript onblur and on keyup and realtime checking for each text box via "this keyword" for individual textbox
 [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/ackMC/) is my jsfiddle link can you help me to modify it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i updated fiddle check may helpful for you

```
$(function () {
    $('#test').blur(function () {
        var text = $(this).val();alert(text);
        $(this).empty().val(text+ ' after clicking');    
    });
});

<input type="text" value="This is some text" id="test" style="width: 150px;" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="button" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/geMtZ/34/

Comment: sorry i have placed wrong js fiddle. right now i  had update the jsfiddle please look into it